# Call Power BI Rest APIs with Power Automate using a dynamic access token that requires new generation every couple hours

Tags: rest, powerbi, power-automate

new to Power BI and Rest API´s here. I have been able to pull data from a REST API with my access code which I have to generate independently every six hours as this code requires regeneration to continually pull data. However, when it comes to automating the pulling of this data from the REST API, I am stuck.

I have attempted to automate pulling the data from the REST API using Power Automate but the necessity to regenerate the token provides an issue. I have also attempted to hardcode the API key in M query but this defeats the security purpose and I do not know how to automate the generation of my access code either.

I have followed this link for help: https://www.vahiddm.com/post/call-power-bi-rest-api-with-power-automate. However, it does not tell me how to automate the generation of my access token and how to input this in power automate.

I am expecting my data to be automated daily in Power BI so I can look at this in my report. I want my data visualization to be up to date.

Does anyone have any advice? I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: How is the code generated? Do you generate the new code with an API call as well?

Comment: Hi! I generate the code using the python request library in google Colab